# Is it possible to modify the WinKey + X menu in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, keyboard-shortcuts, start-menu

This question is related to codewario's comment on his anwser to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70931513/how-to-uninstall-powershell-5-1-on-windows-after-installing-72) question. I have installed version 7 of PowerShell, and I would like this version to be invoked when clicking on the "Windows Powershell" button in the WinKey + X menu, instead of PowerShell v5. Is there a way to achieve this at all?

Comment: You need to physically change the WinX folders to do that. There are many articles online and on Youtube showing how to do this. ['modify winx menu'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27modify+winx+menu%27&t=h_&ia=web) --- ['add powershell core to the winx menu'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27add+powershell+core+to+the+winx+menu%27&t=h_&ia=web)

Answer (score 5):

Here's what helped me without any 3rd party software. You need elevated rights for this.

1. Go to C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows PowerShell (this is where Powershell v5's shortcut in start menu is located at).  >>*Replace USER in the path with your username*
2. Rename the shortcut named "Windows PowerShell" to something else.
3. Now go to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\PowerShell (this is where Powershell v5's shortcut in start menu is located at).
4. Copy the shortcut names "PowerShell (x64) to C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows PowerShell
5. Now rename the copied shortcut in step 4 to "Windows PowerShell".
6. Voila! Now try Win + X and launch PowerShell.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is a WinAero tool called Win+X Menu Editor:

Distribution: https://winaero.com/download-winx-menu-editor-allows-you-to-add-or-remove-winx-menu-items/

Example usage: https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-customize-winx-menu-windows-using-winx-menu-editor/

It uses the [Windows API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-api-list) packaged from the WindowsAPICodePack, so if you're proficient in .net, then you may be able to roll your own solution